# SQL Get Last Record By Date

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
InstallID   |InstallationDate
1           |01-01-2014
1           |01-02-2014
1           |01-03-2014
1           |01-04-2014
2           |01-01-2014
2           |01-02-2014
3           |01-01-2014
3           |01-02-2014
3           |01-03-2014
4           |01-04-2014
4           |01-05-2014
```

where I need to get the latest `installationDate` for each Installation ID

e.g.

```
InstallID   |InstallationDate
1           |01-04-2014
2           |01-02-2014
3           |01-03-2014
4           |01-05-2014
```

Could someone help me how above can be achieve using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFiddleExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89e3b/1)**

```
SELECT t1.InstallID, 
       t1.InstallationDate
FROM yourTable t1
 LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
  ON t1.InstallID = t2.InstallID
  AND t1.InstallationDate < t2.InstallationDate
WHERE t2.InstallID is null
```

Result:

```
| INSTALLID |               INSTALLATIONDATE |
|-----------|--------------------------------|
|         1 | January, 04 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|         2 | January, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|         3 | January, 03 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|         4 | January, 05 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: Magic, how does t1.Installationdate less than t2.Installationdate works? Shouldn't be greater than?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT
    InstallID,
    MAX(InstallationDate)
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY InstallID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

By **[Group By](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)**

```
SELECT InstallID,MAX(InstallationDate)
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY InstallID
```

**(or)**

By **[Row_Number](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**

```
SELECT InstallID,InstallationDate FROM
(
SELECT InstallID,InstallationDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InstallID,InstallationDate ORDER BY InstallID) AS RN,
       COUNT(*) over (PARTITION BY InstallID,InstallationDate) as CN
FROM Table1 
) AS T WHERE RN = CN
```

Comment: lol @ providing more comlicated suggestion, than the first one

Answer (score 0):

```
Select InstallID   , MAX(InstallationDate)
From yourTable
Group  By InstallID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT installid,
       MAX(installationdate)
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY installid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT InstallID, MAX(InstallationDate)
FROM <TableName>
GROUP BY InstallID
```

Answer (score 0):

i think s simpliest way is

```
SELECT t1.InstallID, 
   MAX(t1.InstallationDate)
FROM yourTable t1
Group by t1.InstallID
```